# Third party lead generation service scope access for creating new leads

Tags: rest-api, permissions, leads, lightning-connect, jsforce

**Background**: We're a lead generation service. We sell the leads (as a subscription) to multiple customers. Many of our customers use Salesforce. 
I'm trying to create an app that will create/push new leads to our customer's salesforce instances. Our app should have a scope something like:

- Write access for new Lead objects
- Read access for activity on *only* the Lead objects we created (optional)
- Update access on *only* the Lead objects we created (optional)

**What method should I be using to sync our data with our customer Salesforce instances?** I *think* my best options are:

1. **[Connected App](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=connected_app_overview.htm&type=5)** using the REST api
   [Scope](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&type=5) seems very liberal. `api,id,refresh_token` gives me full read/write access to all of their leads. This will certainly work, however our customers probably don't want us to have access to all their account data. I don't see a way to tighten down the scope.
2. **[Salesforce Connect](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/lightning_connect/units/lightning_connect_introduction)** aka Lightning Connect
   I have little understanding on how this would work, and their docs seem pretty unclear. However, this seems like our application would have a more appropriate scope.

---

FWIW, I've built an connected app oauth2 proof of concept using [jsforce](https://jsforce.github.io/) (not sure if this helps explain my question above)

```js
let jsforce = require('jsforce');
let express = require('express');
let app = express();

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('app started'));

let oauth2 = new jsforce.OAuth2({
    clientId: '...',
    clientSecret: '...',
    redirectUri: 'https://example.com/callback'
});

// Redirect to salesforce
app.get('/auth', function (req, res) {
    res.redirect(oauth2.getAuthorizationUrl());
});

// Get access token for user from salesforce
app.get('/callback', function (req, res) {

    let conn = new jsforce.Connection({ oauth2 });
    let code = req.param('code');
    conn.authorize(code, function(err, userInfo) {
        if (err) { return console.error(err); }

        // TODO: save accessToken, refreshToken, instanceUrl somewhere
        res.send('Cool beans.')
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL/TR: You want to use a Connected App.

### Lightning Connect:

Lightning Connect reaches out to external data in ODATA (2.0 / 4.0) format. No data is pulled into Salesforce, but is kept in the external system. From what you describe you want to hand off your data.

### Connected App & scope

The scope is only liberal at first look. The [documentation says](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=remoteaccess_oauth_scopes.htm&type=5): *api    Allows access to the **current, logged-in user’s account** using APIs, such as REST API and Bulk API.*

So what you do is to request an integration user account (platform permission should do, not a full user) who has limited access to the whole system.

### Considerations

- You might want to offer to push to a custom object e.g. "LeadSubscription" and leave it to the customer to transfer them to leads - they might have their own ideas on lead assignment, reporting etc. (Mostly works for large accounts)
- For "security concerned" user (or licence constraint ones): Don't store the session token, so no "background push" would be possible
- Offer a sample application that can be deployed in Heroku that allows to pull from your API and push to Salesforce (easy to build e.g. using [NodeRED](http://nodered.org) - disclaimer: I maintain the Salesforce nodes).
- Have a AppStore app customers can deploy that talks to your API or UI for interactive import of leads

Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks. This is helpful.

I wouldn't be opposed to keeping the data in our system. That might even be preferred depending upon how it's implemented. i.e. does external data co-mingle w/ saleforce lead objects? Can saleforce users log activity (calls, emails, notes) on external lead data? If so, can we (the external data source) see that activity?

Comment: Also, if we go with a connected app, is there a way to request/create an integration user w/ proper permissions on oauth connect? Ideally the integration would be super simple for our customers, so they don't have to muck around with security settings.

Comment: Glad you like it. Feel free to accept the answer ;-) External data doesn't "co-mingle". What you would do: Provide an OData 4.0 API for your leads and a custom Object e.g. SCLead. In a screen your customers would Pick, Choose and Assign those leads to their sales channel... effectively copying them into Salesforce standard objects. You can package all this into a Salesforce APP your customers can import from our Appexchange

Comment: Accepted. Can you comment on my second comment re: connect app, and oauth automatically  (for our end user) creating an integration user with proper security?

Comment: Creating a user and a matching profile (which defines the security access) is a common activity in Salesforce administration. Shouldn’t be a big deal for your customers. You can actually sign up for a free Developer instance of Salesforce and try everything out